# Issue with types in swift?

Tags: iphone, swift

I did a Team Treehouse code challenge, and I had an issue that I wanted to ask. Basically I created a func inside an enum that takes the specific case of the enum and initializes a given object. It told me to create it inside the enum, but unfortunately when I do this, I came across some errors. I was able to finish the challenge by doing it outside the enum, but I don't think that was exactly what I was supposed to do.

Anyways, my problem was that when it returned the object UIBarButtonItem, if it was assigned to a constant, the type of the constant is "() -> UIBarButtonItem" or depending on how the switch is setup, it could also come out like "(Button) -> UIBarButtonItem". I'm not really sure what the '->' symbol means in this case. Why does it not completely change into the class? What is going on here? In the tutorial right before this, it seems we did the same exact thing, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

```
enum Button {
    case Done(String)
    case Edit(String)

func toUIBarButtonItem () -> UIBarButtonItem {
    switch self {
    case .Done: return UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Done, target: nil, action: nil)
    case .Edit: return UIBarButtonItem(title: "Plain", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        }
    }
}

let done = Button.Done("Done")
let doneButton = Button.toUIBarButtonItem(done)
```

This is the code that I am running, not including the UIBarButtonItem class. I hope this is enough information to understand what I am asking.

Comment: Alright, so why does the variable hold a function instead of the intended object, if that function returns an object? Edited the post to show the code if that helps.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I realized I wasn't calling it on the instance, but that was because before I needed to pass it in so I didn't think it would make sense to call it on itself and then also pass it in. But once I changed the switch to self, it made more sense, I just never changed the part where I actually called it. It still allowed me to pass in done even though it was no longer specified that there was an argument. Surprised it didn't throw any errors, but at least I understand now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `toUIBarButtonItem()` method on the `Button` type instead of a `Button` instance; this is why it does something special: it returns a curried function, which you then bind to `done`. The result, however, is still a function.

What you probably mean to do is invoke the method on your `done` object:

```
let done = Button.Done("Done")
let doneButton = done.toUIBarButtonItem()
```

A more in-depth explanation can be found under http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/

Comment: Okay, now I am understanding. Originally I had the toUIBarButtonItem function taking in a Button type, which meant I had to pass in the done object as a parameter, so I was confused on how I was going to call this method on it, so i just passed it into the function. 

I needed the Button object for the switch, but afterwards I realized I could just remove that and switch on self. So then the rest of my code stayed the same, but I guess I forgot that I didn't need to pass in anything anymore. I'm surprised xcode allowed me to even pass that in when no arguments were specified. Thanks!